# SSRS rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting XML + SQL DataSource

Tags: xml, reporting-services

I have a report that use both a shared SQL DataSource and a local XML DataSource. I've tested the shared SQL DataSource connection and it works. The local XML DataSource is based on a parameter that I send to the report.

The URL is constructed like this: `...Security+Reporting&rs:Command=Render&FileInputHash={hash}`

When I try to open the report, in all ways possible, I get this error:

`The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report server database, or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified. (rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting)`

How can I solve this? Anyone know what's wrong?

**EDIT**:

I've tried to remove the parameter, changed both DataSources to "Windows Authentication" and tested the connection. Both connections work but it still throws the same error when I try to open the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the Report Server set the DataSource settings different even though I had OverwriteDataSource set to true. To solve this, open the report server in your browser, navigate to the report, press "Manage" on the dropdown next to the report name. Then you specify the DataSource settings in the web config.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I resolved whit change the RsReportServer.config added   the code en the section Data

```
<Extension Name="XML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions.XmlDPConnection,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataExtensions">
<Configuration>
    <ConfigName>XML</ConfigName>
</Configuration>
```

and  restart the report service